# Python regex: Negative look-ahead with selection of different length strings

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm searching for a Regex pattern in Python 3.8 that matches a sequence of strings if and only if it's not followed by a selection of other strings. For example, I want to match the pattern "<fruit> and <fruit>" only if the second fruit isn't followed by "ice" or "juice":

```
pat = re.compile(r"(?P<before>apples|bananas)\s+and\s+(?P<after>oranges|lemons)(?!\s*juice|ice)")
```

However, this pattern has problems if the selection of strings in the negative look-ahead aren't of the same length:

```
>>> pat.search("apples and oranges juice")  # doesn't match -> ok

>>> pat.search("apples and oranges ice")  # matches -> not ok
<re.Match object; span=(0, 18), match='apples and oranges'>
```

I ultimately want to use `sub` to replace the matched sequence only if it's not followed by the selection of strings mentioned above. Is it possible to change the behavior of the negative look-ahead to match as much as possible?

Comment: Doesn't `juice|ice` need parentheses around it?

Comment: @FrankYellin Yes, you're right because of the `\s*`, they need parentheses. But parentheses don't solve the actual problem at hand.

Comment: @Ouroborus On my system, `re.compile(r"(?P<before>apples|bananas)\s+and\s+(?P<after>oranges|lemons)(?:((?!\s*juice)|(?!\s*ice)))").search("apples and oranges juice")` unfortunately still matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need a "negative look-ahead assertion".

```
r"what you want(?!(what you do not want to follow))"
```

The following pattern does the job you want.

```
import re

pat = re.compile(r"(apples|bananas)\s+and\s+(oranges|lemons)(?!(\s*(juice|ice)))")

print(pat.search("apples and oranges"))       # Matches
print(pat.search("apples and oranges water")) # Matches

print(pat.search("apple and oranges ice"))    # Does not match
print(pat.search("bananas and lemons juice")) # Does not match
```

Comment: I see. So, I was missing the brackets around my OR group and the content of the negative look-ahead. Thank you!